# TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxx.visualstudio.com

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, registry, penetration-testing, metasploit

When I am trying to connect to my project in TFS by login to my Microsoft account, I am getting some script error like below,

[image]

it was working until yesterday, but I tried to do a Pen Test by installing MetaSploit from Rapid7 and uninstalled it after some-time.

Tried by running "Repair" from VS2013, but no use:(
Can any one advise me to how to get out of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: What's the version of your IE browser?

Answer (score 5):

Please  try below ways to see if it works:

[clear VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and also try to clear **IE cache** first.

Then **clear the Cache Credentials** for the TFS Server on your machine.

You can see them in the Control Panel under: `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager` (or just type "Credentials" into the Start Menu).

Browse down to your tfs server, expand it and then click "Remove".

[image]

Comment: Also I just re-installed my VS, still the problem exists. Any other solution?

Comment: Could you connect to tfs through web portal  with your account?

Comment: The "TF30063" error message indicates that your account doesn't have permission to access TFS. As this [blog](https://nkdagility.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-and-cant-trace-permissions/) described, it is caused when some permissions are denied somewhere because deny takes precedence over any other permission. Also check this .

Comment: Seems the problem is with Microsoft online scripts to connect with TFS. On next day I made a try before formatting my machine, it worked without any error.